# Jenkins pipeline boolean parameter evaluation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, boolean, jenkins-pipeline

I've a Jenkins pipeline that should evaluate a boolean parameter called `saveEar`:

```
stage ('Publish to CIFS'){
  echo String.valueOf(saveEar)
  if ( saveEar ) {
    cifsPublisher alwaysPublishFromMaster: false, continueOnError: false, failOnError: false, publishers: [[
      configName: 'MY-CONFIG', transfers: [[
        cleanRemote: false, 
        excludes: '', 
        flatten: false, 
        makeEmptyDirs: false, 
        noDefaultExcludes: false, 
        patternSeparator: '[, ]+', 
        remoteDirectory: "jenkins-job_" + '$JOB_NAME' + '$BUILD_NUMBER', 
        remoteDirectorySDF: false, 
        removePrefix: 'build/libs', 
        sourceFiles: 'build/libs/my.ear']], 
      usePromotionTimestamp: false, 
      useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, 
      verbose: true
    ]]
  }
}
```

This is the parameter configuration:

```
    <hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
      <name>saveEar</name>
      <description>valore per scegliere se salvare l&apos;EAR generato su XXXX (true =&gt; salva, default false)</description>
      <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    </hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition>
```

I'm expecting that when `saveEar` is `false` Jenkins will not publish over CIFS but it isn't.

This is the pipeline log:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish to CIFS)
[Pipeline] echo
false
[Pipeline] cifsPublisher
CIFS: Connecting from host [jenkins.mydomain]
CIFS: Connecting with configuration [MY-CONFIG] ...
CIFS: Removing WINS from name resolution
CIFS: Setting response timeout [30.000]
CIFS: Setting socket timeout [35.000]
<...>
CIFS: Transferred 1 file(s)
[Pipeline] }
```

Can anyone help clarify this issue please?

Comment: Did you try using `params.saveEar` in the if condition?

Comment: I have to try but I think you point me on the right way: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-27295

Comment: or you can try env.saveEar ?

Comment: @Chen I cant try now I don't think env.saveEar will work. Check the link above...

Comment: @sgargel You can access parameters using params.<variable_name> in pipeline code. From your code format, I believe you are using scripted pipelines. That would fetch the parameter value.

Comment: `params.<variable_name>` do the job. tnx @dot

Comment: @sgargel, Good to know that it resolved your issue. added it as answer. Please mark it as answer for readers who land at this page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To access a parameter within pipeline stages, use `params.variableName`. In your case, you should use `params.saveEar` to access the value.